# how would i test a function that is subscribing to data and then passing it to two other functions

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am learning jest and need help with how to test a specific function in an angular service. This function takes no arguments and subscribes to a get function, the data from the subscription is then passed to two other functions. i have the mock data but am having trouble with the writing of the test.

```
public export(): void {
    this.getDataValues().subscribe((data) => {
      this.exportDelays(data.delay);
      this.exportCancels(data.cancels);
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: is your function inside a service or a component? i might need to adjust my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can test this by mocking the return value of the `getDataValues()` function. in jest this is as simple as this.

```
describe('Service', () => {
  let service: Service;
  
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  // imports, providers and declarations come here::
}).compileComponents();


beforeEach(() => {
  service = TestBed.inject(Service);
});

it('export', () => {
  const mockData = {
    // create an object with the same type as your expected returnData
  }
  jest.spyOn(service, 'getDataValues').mockReturnValue(of(mockData));
  jest.spyOn(service, 'exportDelays').mockImplementation();
  jest.spyOn(service, 'exportCancels').mockImplementation();

  service.export();
 
  expect(service.getDataValues).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(service.exportDelays).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(service.exportCancels).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

notice that you need to return an observable which emits your mockData by passing `of(mockData)` as the returnValue. only then the function can subscribe and trigger the other service methods.